# Show data Horizontally in rdlc report

Tags: c#, .net, report, rdlc

i'm using visual studio 2012 with c# and want to use rdlc for some reports. I'm a little bit familiar with reports and i can show my data on tablix or other controls. But now i need to show data horizontally.
if i use tablix or list data shows vertically :

```
data1
------
data2
------
data3
```

But i wan't them to show like this :

```
data1 | data2 | data3
```

and if the first line is empty go to the second exactly like what a tablix or list do.

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set up the column group approrpriately.

With the same data as above:

[image]

Start with a matrix:

[image]

Remove the row group column and remove any grouping from the column group.

It should look something like this:

[image]

[image]

The end result looks like your requirement:

[image]

Comment: This is the best way to achieve what i want. there is just one additionnal thing to add. we have to put the matrix inside a Rectangle. additional info on this link : http://www.cnblogs.com/rock_chen/archive/2013/04/26/3044815.html

Comment: I can't achieve by the way using your instructions.

Comment: Is it possible to get more details, I can't achieve it aswell, please ?

Comment: Removing the grouping didnt work for me. I ended leaving the grouping in place, and added a "count" property and grouped by that. that worked.