# How to show the table horizontally in (rdlc) report

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I want to show the table horizontally like this:

```
| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | ....

| data5 | data6 | ....
```

For more information, I am using visual studio 2010. and it will go to new line

I saw similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764451/show-data-horizontally-in-rdlc-report) but it goes to new page instead of new line

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2):

in the rdl file or rdlc file in reportproperties set Columns to number of horizontal column you want to show
[image]

for example you want to show 3 column show data and then go to next row

```
column1 | column2  | column3
column4 | column6  | column6
```

in report properties you set columns 3
and set report size width, size of column1
data automatically show in 3 column
now you can use this report as sub report in other report

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got you mean. Can you explain more, Thanks

Comment: Dear Mehdi, I think this way can't solve the problem "show the table horizontally" but it helps me get a new approach to resolve my issue. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

you must crate data table for this

for example for 3 column you Crate DataTable for this purpose

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Data1");
dt.Columns.Add("Data2");
dt.Columns.Add("Data3");
DataRow drow=dt.NewRow();
for(int i=1;i<olddt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
  if(i%3==0 && i!=0)
  {
     dt.Rows.Add(drow); 
     drow=dt.NewRow();
  }
  if(i%3==0)
  {
    drow[0]=olddt[i][Column].ToString();
  }
  if(i%3==1)
  {
     drow[1]=olddt[i][Column].ToString();
  }
  if(i%3==2)
  {
    drow[2]=olddt[i][Column].ToString();
  }
}
```

in this example oldDt is your old data

Comment: Good solution man! it really helped me to achieve what i wanted (y)