# Generate 4 payslip in one page RDLC report

Tags: split, report, rdlc

I want to generate 4 Employee Payslip using **RDLC** report in one page (As like the attach image). I can split the page into two column but in the viewer it does not show two column, after export PDF I can see.

So if any one give me idea how to generate 4 payslip in one page also showed in viewer.

[image]

Comment: how to you can get this rdlc. i am working on that but dont know how to get multiple in single rdlc @Isalm

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subreport for a single Employee Payslip or wrap it inside a rectangle. This subreport (or rectangle) you can then place inside a datamatrix that you can manipulate to grow horizontally by applying column-grouping.

If you set everything up correctly then this should of course grow horizontally, placing 2 Employee Payslips next to each other and breaking to the next line and eventually next page when the space ran out.

Here is a simple example of making the tablix grow horizontally: [Show data Horizontally in rdlc report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764451/show-data-horizontally-in-rdlc-report)